setManufacturerData() method in the Android Bluetooth library is allowing advertisements with non-matching manufacturer data to proceed
I am invoking the method below from the Android BLE library to configure the scan filter. I am using both the manufacturer ID and manufacturer data as criteria for filtering. However, I am encountering an intermittent issue where advertisements with non-matching manufacturer data are still being processed.
For example: My manufacturer data filter criteria are set to byteArrayof(0x0A, 0x0A), but if the product advertises different data, such as byteArrayof(0x0A, 0x0B), the filter criteria seem to be compromised and are allowing this data to pass through.
How can I solve the issue, I believe its a Android BLE library issue? Has anyone faced the same issue?
public Builder setManufacturerData(int manufacturerId, byte[] manufacturerData) {
            if (manufacturerData != null && manufacturerId < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid manufacture id");
            }
            mManufacturerId = manufacturerId;
            mManufacturerData = manufacturerData;
            mManufacturerDataMask = null; // clear manufacturer data mask
            return this;
        }
```



Did you consider the mask?

@Emil , I haven't tried using the mask yet. Are you suggesting that I should include the mask in the scan filter? If so, which byte should I specify for the mask? Have you ever experience this inconsistent behaviour with scanfilter?
